# Adding Javascript variables to HTML elements

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

So, I have some code that should do four things:

- remove the ".mp4" extension from every title
- change my video category
- put the same description in all of the videos
- put the same keywords in all of the videos

Note: All of this would be done on the YouTube upload page. I'm using Greasemonkey in Mozilla Firefox.

I wrote this, but my question is: how do I change the HTML title in the actual HTML page to the new title (which is a Javascript variable)?

This is my code:

```
function remove_mp4()
{
   var title = document.getElementsByName("title").value;
   var new_title = title.replace(title.match(".mp4"), "");
}
function add_description()
{
   var description = document.getElementsByName("description").value;
   var new_description = "Subscribe."
}
function add_keywords()
{
   var keywords = document.getElementsByName("keywords").value;
   var new_keywords = prompt("Enter keywords.", "");
}
function change_category()
{
   var category = document.getElementsByName("category").value;
   var new_category = "<option value="27">Education</option>"
}
remove_mp4();
add_description();
add_keywords();
change_category();
```

Note: If you see any mistakes in the JavaScript code, please let me know.

Note 2: If you wonder why I stored the current HTML values in variables, that's because I think I will have to use them in order to replace HTML values (I may be wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your question is only about the title changing, and not about the rest; also, I assume you mean changing all elements in the document that have "title" as `name` attribute, and not the document title.

In that case, you could indeed use `document.getElementsByName("title")`.

To handle the `name="title"` elements, you could do:

```
titleElems=document.getElementsByName("title");
for(i=0;i<titleElems.length;i++){
    titleInner=titleElems[i].innerHTML;
    titleElems[i].innerHTML=titleInner.replace(titleInner.match(".mp4"), "");
}
```

For the `name="description"` element, use this: (assuming there's only **one** `name="description"` element on the page, or you want the first one)

```
document.getElementsByName("description")[0].value="Subscribe.";
```

I wasn't really sure about the keywords (I haven't got a YouTube page in front of me right now), so this assumes it's a text field/area just like the description:

```
document.getElementsByName("keywords")[0].value=prompt("Please enter keywords:","");
```

Again, based on your question which just sets the `.value` of the category thingy:

```
document.getElementsByName("description")[0].value="<option value='27'>Education</option>";
```

At the last one, though, note that I changed the `"27"` into `'27'`: you can't put double quotes inside a double-quoted string assuming they're handled just like any other character :)

Did this help a little more? :)

Comment: Yes, it did, thanks. Then we got add_description function. What it would do, it would just change blank description box (description is a name attribute of an input HTMl tag) into my default one, which is "Subscribe.". After that, we have got add_keywords(). Firstly, I would enter the keywords that I want and than it would change default, blank keywords (which is again, name attribute) with mine. And lastly, change_category() would just select Education as my Youtube category. Hope I made this a bit more clearer. :)

Comment: ByTheWay, the reason why I looped on every element of the generated `titleelems` is that `document.getElementsByName` gives back an **array** (watch the name, "Element**s**"). You can't just access an array as an element :)

Comment: I edited my answer to handle the other parts of the questions as well, did this help? (BTW, sorry for the slightly late answer, I took my time writing my extended answer :P)

Comment: I created a new script, with source code of the site here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831542/javascript-functions-for-changing-html-elements. Can you review that and tell me is it OK (my code). Thanks.

Comment: I provided an answer on the question you linked; though **never** fork a question into a new one when there isn't a real reason why to fork; you could have just put the sample HTML code into this question. It wouldn't have been a bad idea anyway :) And you see what's the result: look at the comments at the forked question.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of things have been covered already, but still i would like to remind you that if you are looking for cross browser compatibility innerHTML won't be enough, as you may need innerText too  or textContent to tackle some old versions of IE or even using some other way to modify the content of an element.

As a side note innerHTML is considered from a great majority of people as deprecated though some others still use it. (i'm not here to debate about is it good or not to use it but this is just a little remark for you to checkabout)

Regarding remarks, i would suggest minimizing the number of functions you create by creating some more generic versions for editing or adding purposes, eg you could do the following :

```
/*
*  @param $affectedElements the collection of elements to be changed      
*  @param $attribute here means the attribute to be added to each of those elements
*  @param $attributeValue the value of that attribute
*/
function add($affectedElements, $attribute, $attributeValue){
  for(int i=0; i<$affectedElements.length; i++){
    ($affectedElements[i]).setAttribute($attribute, $attributeValue);
  }
}
```

If you use a global function to do the work for you, not only your coce is gonna be easier to maintain but also you'll avoid fetching for elements in the DOM many many times, which will considerably make your script run faster. For example, in your previous code you fetch the DOM for a set of specific elements before you can add a value to them, in other words everytime your function is executed you'll have to go through the whole DOM to retrieve your elements, while if you just fetch your elements once then store in a var and just pass them to a function that's focusing on adding or changing only, you're clearly avoiding some repetitive tasks to be done.

Concerning the last function i think code is still incomplete, but i would suggest you use the built in methods for manipulating HTMLOption stuff, if i remember well, using plain JavaScript you'll find yourself typing this :

```
var category = document.getElem.... . options[put-index-here];
//JavaScript also lets you create <option> elements with the Option() constructor
```

Anyway, my point is that you would better use JavaScript's available methods to do the work instead of relying on innerHTML fpr anything you may need, i know innerHTML is the simplest and fastest way to get your work done, but if i can say it's like if you built a whole HTML page using  and  tags only instead of using various semantic tags that would help make everything clearer.

As a last point for future use, if you're interested by jQuery, this will give you a different way to manipulate your DOM through CSS selectors in a much more advanced way than plain JavaScript can do.

you can check out this link too :
[replacement for innerHTML](http://www.bestcodingpractices.com/break_your_innerhtml_addiction-2719.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sry, but your question is not quite clear. What exactly is your *HTML title* that you are referring to?

If it's an element that you wish to modify, use this :

```
element.setAttribute('title', 'new-title-here');
```

If you want to modify the window title (shown in the browser tab), you can do the following :

```
document.title = "the new title";
```

Comment: I want to modify the title, which is an HTML element. Do i use "element" in "element.setAttribute", or I replace "element" with my element name... ex. <input name="trash" />, so than it would be trash.setAttribute('title', 'new_title');

Comment: `element` is a variable that holds a reference to your dom object. so, you can replace element with something like `document.getElementById("title").setAttribute('key','value')`

Answer (score 0):

The `<title>` element is an *invisible* one, it is only displayed indirectly - in the window or tab title. This means that you want to change whatever is displayed in the window/tab title and not the HTML code itself. You can do this by changing the [`document.title` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.title):

```
function remove_mp4()
{
  document.title = document.title.replace(title.match(".mp4"), "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've reading elements from `.value` property, so you should write back it too:

```
document.getElementsByName("title").value = new_title
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to changing text content in an element called title try using `innerHTML`

```
 var title = document.getElementsByName("title").value;
 document.getElementsByName("title").innerHTML = title.replace(title.match(".mp4"), "");
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML