# Javascript functions for changing HTML elements

Tags: javascript

OK guys, I did this, and I think this covers 3 out of 4 of my functions :

- Removing ".mp4" extension
- Adding my own description
- Adding keywords
- Changing category (**not done**)

  ```
  function remove_mp4()
  {
     var title = document.getElementsByName("title").value;
     document.getElementsByName("title").innerHTML = title.replace(title.match(".mp4"), "");

  }
  function add_description()
  {
     var new_description = "Sample."
     document.getElementsByName("description").innerHTML = new_description;
  }
  function add_keywords()
  {
     var new_keywords = prompt("Unesite kljucne rijeci.", "");
     document.getElementsByName("keywords").innerHTML = new_keywords;
  }
  function change_category()
  {
     var category = document.getElementsByName("category").value;
  }
      remove_mp4();
      add_description();
      add_keywords();
      change_category();
  ```

Thing that I don't know is, how to change the category. Website code (website that I want to change) is here :

```
<label>
                <h4 class="category-header">Kategorija</h4>
                <span class="yt-uix-form-input-select "><span class="yt-uix-form-input-select-content"><img src="my_videos_upload_datoteke/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" class="yt-uix-form-input-select-arrow"><span class="yt-uix-form-input-select-value">Odaberite kategoriju</span></span><select class="yt-uix-form-input-select-element category-input" name="category">        <option selected="selected" value="">Odaberite kategoriju</option>
    <option value="2">Automobili i vozila</option>
<option value="1">Film i animacija</option>
<option value="10">Glazba</option>
<option value="20">Igre</option>
<option value="23">Komedija</option>
<option value="15">Kućni ljubimci i životinje</option>
<option value="22">Ljudi i blogovi</option>
<option value="29">Neprofitne organizacije i aktivisti</option>
<option value="27">Obrazovanje</option>
<option value="26">Praktični savjeti i stil</option>
<option value="19">Putovanja i događaji</option>
<option value="17">Sportovi</option>
<option value="25">Vijesti i politika</option>
<option value="24">Zabava</option>
<option value="28">Znanost i tehnologija</option>
```

Also, I want to include my webiste URL into description (http://www.sample.com/), but everytime i try, I get an error (because Javascript reads "//" as one line comment), so any ideas how to fix that 2 things?

Note : If you think some parts of script would not work, please write it. Thanks.

Comment: "What question?" Focus on one thing and only one thing. Provide a *minimal* (but complete) test-case showing the behavior .. and remove the extra unrelated stuff.

Comment: @TheGhost It's nearly impossible to answer the question, because I don't know what the requirements are for the website. In other words: what does the website do? Is it a catalogue? Does it use a database (and which one)?

Comment: It's Youtube website, wanted to create a bot that automatically fills four forms in Youtube upload page (that HTML code snippet is a snippet from content related to unresolved function - change_category()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First about the .mp3 extension: have you tested your `remove_mp3()` function? You're trying to set the `innerHTML` of an array there, I'll show you what I mean:

I use Chrome, but I'm sure in Firefox you have a JS console as well. Try to enter `document.getElementsByName("title")` in there and you'll see that you get an **array** back. You'll probably want to change the title of every `title`-element, so you'll have to loop through them:

```
titleElems=document.getElementsByName("title");
for(i=0;i<titleElems.length;i++){
    titleInner=titleElems[i].innerHTML;
    titleElems[i].innerHTML=titleInner.replace(titleInner.match(".mp4"), "");
}
```

Then on the category part: an `<option>` in a drop-down list is by definition selected when it **has** a `selection` attribute. Thus, remove that attribute and add it to the wanted option to be selected:

```
catChildNodes=document.getElementsByName("category")[0].childNodes;
catChildNotes[1].removeAttribute("selected");
for(i=0;i<catChildNodes.length;i++){
    if(catChildNodes[i].value="15") //Please change the "15" into something you want; I don't know which one you want to choose :)
        catChildNodes[i].setAttribute("selected",""); //it doesn't matter it's empty; it just matters the attrib. exists :)
}
```

Note this doesn't update the selection in the browser window (at least not in Chrome Mac); but *internally* it does.

And, about the link in a description: are you putting quotes around the link? (in the JS) It shouldn't read `"//"` as a comment... (`alert("//")` does work as expected) Please show what you're trying.

Something completely different, relating to Note 2 in your original question: you do not need to store a value you want to assign to a variable in another variable first, in another words: `a="hello"; b=a;` is equal to: (with the exception of an extra variable `a` used of course) `b="hello";` and thus: `a="hello"; document.getElementsByName("title").value=a;` is (approx.) equal to `document.getElementsByName("title").value="hello";`.